# does tensorflow einsumdepends on the size of the inputs?

Tags: python, tensorflow, matrix

I am using the following code to construct a density matrix from a set of decomposed Cholesky matrix:

```
def density_matrix_from_T(tmatrix):
"""
Gets density matrices from T matrices and normalizes them.

Args:
    tmatrix (`tf.Tensor`): A tensor (N, hilbert_size, hilbert_size)
                           representing N valid T matrices.

Returns:
    rho (`tf.Tensor`): A tensor of shape (N, hilbert_size, hilbert_size)
                       representing N density matrices.
"""

T = tmatrix
T_dagger = tf.transpose(T, perm=[0, 2, 1], conjugate=True)
proper_dm = tf.matmul(T_dagger, T)
all_traces = tf.linalg.trace(proper_dm)
all_traces = tf.reshape(1 / all_traces, (-1, 1))
rho = tf.einsum("bij,bk->bij", proper_dm, all_traces)

return rho
```

My question regards the line `rho = tf.einsum("bij,bk->bij", proper_dm, all_traces)`: I don't think I understand `tf.einsum` quite well. This code works good when the inputs are matrices of size `16x16` but it does not works good for a `256x256`. The `rho` matrix should be similar to another reference matrix that I am using but in the first case (dimension 4, 16x16 matrix) this is good as the 'similarity' is 0.99, but in the second case I can't get anything better than 0.005 which is very very bad. I am not sure if this piece of code is giving the desired result.

Thus the question is: does the `tf.einsum` depends somehow on the size of the input matrix? Is it right for a 256x256 matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dimensions of the input matrices shouldn't matter. They are [arbitrarily selected.](https://docs.w3cub.com/tensorflow%7Epython/tf/einsum.html)

Comment: I believe I have been hasty. It is clear now that it is independent. Thanks

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).